# Pinky commandline tool on mac?

Tags: macos, command-line

I'm looking for the `pinky` command line tool on Mac OS X.  It's not found in MacPorts.  I am trying to utilize a script that uses it.  I would hate to have to go through and strip out all the references to pinky and replace them with `finger`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinky is part of [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) and coreutils is available from several sources. While trying to avoid any religious wars over which packaging system is the best possible option for OS/X, I personally use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) which I recommend in this case too.

Using Homebrew, you can install GNU coreutils with `brew install coreutils` after which pinky will be at your disposal as `gpinky` (Homebrew tries to avoid duplicating any names which may be in use already, thus most GNU software has g in front of the command).

Using MacPorts, you can probably install GNU coreutils with `port install coreutils` after which pinky should be at your disposal as `pinky`.

As my experience is limited with MacPorts and I have Homebrew already installed on all my Macs, I tested this only with Homebrew. So no guarantees that instructions for MacPorts are correct, though I did check that GNU coreutils is [packaged](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/coreutils/Portfile) in MacPorts.

Comment: It's `gpinky` in MacPorts too.